# Configure gorm with a highly available postgres cluster

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

We are looking to configure gorm (https://gorm.io) with a highly available postgres cluster. Currently, when we fail over the primary postgres node we start to see error messages such as "driver: bad connection" in the logs. We are hoping there is a way to configure the connection pool such that it can detect the "bad connections", remove them from the pool, and establish news connections. Is this a possibility?

Tried failing over the primary postgres node to determine if gorm would establish new connections.

Comment: Can you specify what "when we fail over the primary postgres node" means code-wise?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are using gremlin to perform the failover of the primary Postgres node and the postgres cluster is managed via Patroni.